# SQL query to populate data for invoices in current month based the fiscal month being current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that can be used as a "running query" where it pulls data for the current month. The query is to pull invoice information each month to review and we have a fiscal calendar, which I already have joined so the invoices are associated with the Fiscal month and year. The query I have is a union across 5 databases and I put the where clause in each union (5 times)

Returns Results:

```
SELECT 
.... , 
bcal.fiscalmonthname as FiscalMonth, 
bcal.yearnbr as FiscalYr,
..... , 
CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST (bi.invoice_date AS DATE), 101) as Invoice_Date, 
.... , 
bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr as Fiscal_Yr_Mon
FROM DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    **INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.ref_calendar_tbl AS bcal ON bi.invoice_date = bcal.date**
    INNER JOIN DB1....
        INNER JOIN DB1....                                                       
        INNER JOIN DB1....                               
        INNER JOIN DB1....                                           
        INNER JOIN DB1....  
        INNER JOIN Server2.DB3....

WHERE **bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN ('2024-03')** AND ....

GROUP BY ....

UNION

SELECT 
.... , 
tbcal.fiscalmonthname as FiscalMonth, 
tbcal.yearnbr as FiscalYr,
 ..... ,
CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST (tbi.invoice_date AS DATE), 101) as Invoice_Date,
..... ,  
tbcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr as Fiscal_Yr_Mon
FROM DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    **INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.ref_calendar_tbl AS tbcal ON tbi.invoice_date = tbcal.date**
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....                                                               
        INNER JOIN DB2....                                                           
        INNER JOIN DB2....                                                           
        INNER JOIN DB2....
        INNER JOIN Server2.DB3...
WHERE ** tbcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN ('2024-03')** AND ....
GROUP BY ....

ORDER BY Prod_Group ASC,
     mill_id ASC,
     Company_Customer ASC,
     Mill_Invoice# ASC
```

Results are correct using the associated fiscal year-month

| Invc_Date | Fiscal_Yr_Mon |
| --- | --- |
| 2/25/2024 | 2024-03 |
| 2/26/2024 | 2024-03 |
| 3/2/2024 | 2024-03 |

No Results:

```
SELECT 
.... , 
bcal.fiscalmonthname as FiscalMonth, 
bcal.yearnbr as FiscalYr, 
..... , 
CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST (bi.invoice_date AS DATE), 101) as Invoice_Date, 
.... , 
bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr as Fiscal_Yr_Mon
FROM DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    INNER JOIN DB1....
    **INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.ref_calendar_tbl AS bcal ON bi.invoice_date = bcal.date**
    INNER JOIN DB1....
        INNER JOIN DB1....                                                       
        INNER JOIN DB1....                               
        INNER JOIN DB1....                                           
        INNER JOIN DB1....  
        INNER JOIN Server2.DB3....

WHERE **bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM'))** AND ....

GROUP BY ....

UNION

SELECT 
.... , 
tbcal.fiscalmonthname as FiscalMonth, 
tbcal.yearnbr as FiscalYr, 
..... ,
CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST (tbi.invoice_date AS DATE), 101) as Invoice_Date, 
..... ,  
tbcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr as Fiscal_Yr_Mon
FROM DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    **INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.ref_calendar_tbl AS tbcal ON tbi.invoice_date = tbcal.date**
    INNER JOIN DB2....
    INNER JOIN DB2....                                                               
        INNER JOIN DB2....                                                           
        INNER JOIN DB2....                                                           
        INNER JOIN DB2....
        INNER JOIN Server2.DB3...
WHERE **tbcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM'))** AND ....
GROUP BY ....

ORDER BY ...
```

Expectation: when the query is run in March, it only returns invoices with March fiscal month, when query is run in April, it only returns invoices with April fiscal month, etc.

Tried using `WHERE bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM'))` and returns no results (no error message either)

When I use `WHERE bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN ('2024-03')` results return with all invoices in fiscal month March correctly

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in the first place?

Comment: `FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM')` did you check what that actually returns..? I suspect it's not what you think (it's not `'2024-03'` if you run it today). .Net date formatting characters are **case sensitive**.

Comment: As a side note, is a `UNION` really what you want here? Are you really going to have identical rows you need to omit in the different databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using FORMAT function in the WHERE clause?

Istead of using FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM'),I woul replace to CONVERT(varchar(7), GETDATE(), 120) for the current month.

Replace:

```
WHERE bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM')) AND (...)
```

with:

```
WHERE bcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (CONVERT(varchar(7), GETDATE(), 120)) AND (...)
```

AND replace

```
WHERE tbcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (FORMAT(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM')) AND (...)
```

with:

```
WHERE tbcal.fiscalyearmonthnbr IN (CONVERT(varchar(7), GETDATE(), 120)) AND (...)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was trying to google this one but it works with the convert! Appreciate it!